# Tracking Request and Page Events in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to the whole chrome extension thing. I read on content scripts and background scripts and it is very confusing for my particular case.

I want to track request events like OnBeforeSendHeaders up until OnCompleted, once these events fire I then want to write a flag in a place that I can access from my C# application (am thinking js's localstorage).

For example:
When OnBeforeSendHeaders gets fired for a certain request, I want to write "1" flag to localstorage, and then I can read the sqlite file of that localstorage database from my C# application.

What confuses me is where I should write the request events monitor, in the background script or content script?

I understand that I can't use localstorage in the content script and it is recommended to use Chrome Storage API (but my problem with that is that I want to access these stored values from my C#, so sqlite that localstorage generates seems perfect).

So how I can achieve something like that? It is totally confusing.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @elegant-user that's just it, I don't know where to write my code...dont know how to start.. the whole restrictions on the localstorage is making it hard to choose to write all the code in the content script

Comment: I would suggest you to read the official documentation. It is very easy to understand and there several sample code available.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples

Comment: Consider using [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API to communicate with your C# app because AFAIK there's no guarantee Chrome would write the value immediately to the disk.

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought about that (NativeMessaging), was hoping to avoid it...but seens there is no other choice

Comment: @elegant-user thanks for this massive resource of extensions..I will see which one is closer to my case